# Animate img replacement on jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace some logo images on a web site with a all white version of the same image. The idea is that when you hover over the image you see the logo in white with a coloured background (done in css)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.la-item img').hover(function() {
      var image = jQuery(this).attr('data-imagenormal')+'-white.png';
      jQuery(this).attr("src", image)
      jQuery(this).addClass("circleitem")

    }, function() {

        var image = jQuery(this).attr('data-imagenormal')+'.png';
        jQuery(this).attr("src", image )
        jQuery(this).removeClass("circleitem")
    });
  });
```

This actually looks great, but I would like it to animate the change over 2 seconds. I've tried using this.animate, but it does not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.la-item img').hover(function() {
     var image = jQuery(this).attr('data-imagenormal')+'-white.png';
      jQuery(this).animate({
      jQuery(this).attr("src", image)
      jQuery(this).addClass("circleitem")
        )}
    }, function() {
        var color = jQuery(this).attr('data-imagenormal')+'.png';
        jQuery(this).animate({
        jQuery(this).attr("src", color )
        jQuery(this).removeClass("circleitem")
    });
    })
  });
```

Comment: share the code you tried

Comment: animate can only animate css properties...

Comment: ok. thank you. Do you know of a way to achieve this, if I need to both change the image and the css class?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```
<img src="one.png" id="one" />

//Script
$('#one').hover(function() {

// increase the 500 to larger values to lengthen the duration of the fadeout 
   // and/or fadein
$('#one').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#one').attr("src","/newImage.png");
    //here you can add or remove class
    $('#one').fadeIn(500);
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<img>` tag, just use CSS and backgrounds.

For example (I'm not trying to have the same structure than yours) :

HTML

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #whatyouwhant;
    background-image: url('yourlogo.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: .3s;
}

#logo:hover {
    background-image: url('yourwhitelogo.png');
}
```

You can combine background colors and transparent PNGs.

You can use this technique and still change the background with jQuery :

```
$('.matchyourelements').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).data('imagenormal')+'-white.png');
});
```